# Create new row in data-frame if date exists in a list and not in the data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `list` called `date_str_list` that look like:

```
date_str_list:  ['2014-04-21' '2014-04-22' '2014-04-23' ..
 '2014-12-24' '2014-12-25' '2014-12-26']
```

I have a df called `df1` that looks like:

```
              Wave  Dept    Cumulative_Orders                  Description
date                    
21/04/2014  wave_2     A                   69       Distribution/Wholesale  
23/04/2014  wave_2     A                  179       Distribution/Wholesale  
24/04/2014  wave_2     A                  238       Distribution/Wholesale  
         :       :     :                    :                            :  
24/12/2014  wave_2     A                 8151       Distribution/Wholesale  
25/12/2014  wave_2     A                 8193       Distribution/Wholesale  
26/12/2014  wave_2     A                 8291       Distribution/Wholesale
```

Is it possible to apply `date_str_list` to `df1` creating rows in `df1` where there is a date in `date_str_list` but not in `df1`?  For example in `df1` for `Dept A` there is no row of data for date `22/04/2014` but that date exists in `date_str_list`.  Once the row with the date has been created I'd like to back fill with the previous value.

Below is an example final output:

```
              Wave  Dept    Cumulative_Orders                  Description
date                    
21/04/2014  wave_2     A                   69       Distribution/Wholesale  
22/04/2014  wave_2     A                   69       Distribution/Wholesale
23/04/2014  wave_2     A                  179       Distribution/Wholesale  
24/04/2014  wave_2     A                  238       Distribution/Wholesale  
         :       :     :                    :                            :  
24/12/2014  wave_2     A                 8151       Distribution/Wholesale  
25/12/2014  wave_2     A                 8193       Distribution/Wholesale  
26/12/2014  wave_2     A                 8291       Distribution/Wholesale
```

I can back fill using `df1.bfill(axis ='rows')` but do not know how to create a new row in the data-frame.

Comment: i think you can just reindex the index with your list and then forward fill : `df.reindex(date_list).ffill()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use @anky suggestion but first you have to add to a same format the date from `df1` index and your `date_str_list`, you can achieve this by using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
date_str_list = ['2014-04-21' ,'2014-04-22', '2014-04-23', '2014-12-24', '2014-12-25', '2014-12-26']
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df1 = df1.reindex(map(pd.to_datetime, date_str_list)).ffill()
df1
```

output:

[image]